# Localization and Ajax request Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm trying to translate views which  some of them are loaded via Ajax, so the problem is that even the locale is I get always the text of the default locale, to be clear, this how my files looks :

app/config/app.php :

```
     //...
    'languages' => array('fr', 'en'),

    'locale' => 'fr',
     //...
```

routes.php

```
  if(!Request::ajax()) { 
// Set locale
$locale = Request::segment(1);

if(in_array($locale, Config::get('app.languages'))) {

    App::setLocale($locale);

    Session::put('locale', $locale);

} else {
    $locale = null;
    Session::put('locale', $locale);
}
$locale = Session::get('locale') or null;
```

}

```
// Group by locale
  Route::group(
array( 'prefix' => $locale ), function () {
    // Home controller
    Route::get('/' . Config::get('app.lcoale'), array( 'uses' =>     'HomeController@getIndex', 'as' => '/' ));

 //...
```

The ajax routes are out of the group prefixed by the locale :

```
 Route::group(
     array( 'prefix' => 'ajax', 'namespace' => 'Ajax', 'before' => 'ajax' ), function () {
 //...
```

When I check the current locale after sending ajax request   `Config::get('app.locale')`: It show me the correct locale, but the rendered text in the view is of the default locale (fr).

It makes a sense for you ?, Please help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved for me.

```
 Route::filter('ajax', function(){

 if(! Request::ajax())
 {
App::abort(404);
}

    // Set again the locale
    if(Session::has('locale'))
    App::setLocale(Session::get('locale'));
 });
```